# How I do programmatically replace transparency in images in a pdf with the color white?

Tags: python, image-processing, pdf-generation

I am building an interface to a postal printing service where you can upload pdf documents to be printed, enveloped and stamped for postal delivery. The problem is that some of the PDFs contain transparent images. How can I replace the transparency with white programmatically? Preferably in python.

Comment: Why would you want to remove the transparent images? Wouldn't it be a better user experience to replace the transparency in images with a solid colour (eg. the colour of the paper) and not remove them from the PDF file?

Comment: Yes, this is a relevant comment. I have re-phrased the question to be how I can replace transparency with white.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to explain what you've already tried to do in order to solve your problem, and what's not working. Check [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more.

Comment: What shall happen with areas which are only partially transparent?